# Prompt user for payment amount using bitcoin bip 70?

Tags: bitcoind, bip70-payment-protocol

When specifying the details for the payment object I have noticed that if I leave **amount** blank I am not prompted to enter an amount by the bitcoin-qt 0.9 client.

```
xpd = x.PaymentDetails()
xpd.time = int(time())
xpd.outputs.add(amount = 10000000, script = serialized_script)
xpd.memo = 'this is xpd memo'
xpdstring = xpd.SerializeToString()
xpr = x.PaymentRequest()
xpr.serialized_payment_details = xpd.SerializeToString()
xprstring = xpd.SerializeToString()
```

If I do not specify an amount then it is set to zero by default and I am presented with the error that the bitcoin amount is too small and is considered 'dust'.

Please can someone help me understand how to prompt the user for a deposit amount if the amount field is blank?

Thanks.

Additionally I should note that I am using the testnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3095) in Bitcoin-QT.

Comment: Much appreciated :)